# Custom access log in aiohttp

Tags: python, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I want to have additional attributes of request to be logged in access log of aiohttp server. 
For example I have middleware, that adds `user` attribute to each request, and I want to store this value inside `extra` attribute for access log records. Documentation [suggests](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/logging.html#format-specification) to overwrite `aiohttp.helpers.AccessLogger` which indeed seems to be a good starts, but what do I do next, where do I put instance of my custom logger? I looked through the code and it looks like that is not possible on application creation stage, but rather on application run. But I'm running application using different approaches, so this it's not that convenient to modify startup in several places (for example locally I'm using `aiohttp-devtools runserver` and gunicorn for deployment).

So what should be correct approach here?
(Also I'd like to do the same for error log, but that seems even more complex, so for now I'm just using another middleware that catches errors and creates log records I need).

Answer (score 0):

Taking into account that development logging config is usually very different from production one keeping two different approaches for `gunicorn` and `aiohttp-devtools` are totally fine.

For dev server you perhaps need to log everything on a console, staging and production writes logs differently.

Comment: I think you are partially right here. It's true that logging for development and production may be different, but this is about "how" it's logged. And this is covered by handlers. My question is rather about "what" is logged. And I'd like it to be in one place, no matter in what env an app is running. I think your answer confirms that legal ways to do this seems to be overcomplicated for me. So I will go with a bit illegal. I'm going to subclass `Application` even if this is discouraged  and override `_make_handler` method. Hopefully there would be a better way to do this in further versions.

Comment: Btw, want to use this chance and say thank you for this great library.

Comment: Thank you very much. I suggest moving the discussion into aiohttp github bugtracker. Please create an issue. I feel your pain, we should find a solution. It covers not only logging but all connection related parameters.